# How can i reduce the cost of resources kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to cut costs on my development environment. Now my environment works 24 hours, but in fact it is used only a couple of hours a day. I would like to make my environment work only 8 hours a day, and if there are no requests there, it will be minimized to 0 until a request arrives. I would like that when requesting a link to my environment, it would restore work. Tell me how to do this? A general purpose, Scale to Zero component for Kubernetes when in's not using.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to scale to zero, but a minimum amount (1 node) would be ok? I'm confirming some information and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ok, just confirmed, you can't scale GKE to absolute zero, but there is some good alternatives to reduce your costs. First I'd like to clarify one thing, you mentioned "when requesting a link to my environment, it would restore work". What kind of link are you mentioning? if you could clarify your overall need it will be easier to provide an accurate solution.

Comment: When you scale your deployment to zero pods, you are still using the node because some `kube-system` namespaced pods will be still running on that node, but I am not sure if you are being billed for that usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - Osiris (https://github.com/deislabs/osiris). This system scale down all my deployments that not using 1h in my case.

Comment: I just advice to proceed carefully as the page states **Osiris, as a concept, is highly experimental and currently remains under heavy development**.
I would suggest you to use Google's auto scaler to near zero as it's a more stable solution.